# Double ended queue class in the .Net Framework

Tags: .net, data-structures, workflow-foundation-4

As I was trying to understand some parts of the `WorkflowApplication` class I ran into a class named `System.Activities.Quack<T>`.  The [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Activities/System/Activities/Quack.cs) shows this to be a double ended queue, but I'm curious.  Is there a legitimate reason that the class is named Quack, or is this someone trying to be funny with an internal framework class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name Quack is an amalgamation of Queue and Stack; Qu-ack. It's a collection that acts both as a queue and a stack.

It may be more commonly known as a [double-ended queue, or a Deque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue).

Comment: Ah - I knew it had to be something like that, but I wasn't creative enough to come up with it.  Awesome.

Comment: Yes. Somebody being funny with their class names. `Deque` is a well-understood data structure. `Quack` not so much.